# Microsoft Lists - Populate today's date in the Start Date column, by Status column selection, and not have it update when the status is changed

Tags: list, sharepoint

Is this possible in MS Lists? An IF statement needs 2 options and I can get it to populate, but don't want the Start Date to update/change once it's populated. The Status column will go from In Progress to Completed. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Whether Start Date column is a date and time column or a calculated column?

How to use IF statement? Is it used on the Start Date column or Status column?

Based on your description, I understand that you want to Start Date column filled in with today's date.

You could set the default time of Start Date column as Today's date.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, let me try to explain again. I have a "Progress" column and a "Start Date" column. When someone selects "In Progress" in the Progress column, I want today's date to populate in the "Start Date" column. The problem is that I don't want the start date to update when the Progress column is changed to "Complete". I only want Start Date to populate with today's date when "In Progress" is selected in the Progress column, and I want it to remain unchanged after that.

Comment: =IF(Progress="In Progress",TODAY(),"")
This will populate the "Start Date" column with today's date, but when the "In Progress" column is updated to "Complete", it removes the date. I want the date to remain once it populates.

Comment: What are the values in the "Progress" column? Are there other values in the "Progress" column besides "In Progress" and "Complete"? What is the default value of "Progress" column?

Comment: You could try following formula: =IF(OR(Progress="In Progress", Progress="Complete"),TODAY(),"")

Comment: Wouldn't that update the date when the status changes from "In Progress" to "Complete" (or any other option), and if I chose any other value it would remove the date? The current Progress options are - Not Started, In Progress, On Hold, Completed. I want the date to populate only when "In Progress" is chosen, and be permanent.

Comment: Per my knowledge and test, making today's date populate in the "Start Date" column only when "In Progress" is chosen and be permanent is not available.